# Automator Applescript - Editing "Watch Me Do" action doesn't work

Tags: applescript, automator

I am trying to get a workflow in Automator.
I recorded action via "Watch Me Do". And when I replayed, it works well.

When I dragged this action into AppleScript editor, it does not work anymore.

Screenshots :
[image]

[image]

All I want is to have something that works for `commune_1` and editing the script to do the same actions for `commune_2`, `commune_3` and so on.